# Calling a Cron Trigger stored in JDBCJobStore programmatically

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have a Cron Trigger configured using the JDBCJobStore since we will be running the app within a clustered environment.

I have the CronTrigger running every 10AM, everything is working great.

How would I programmatically start this Cron Trigger "On-Deman".  Any code sample appreciated.

I'm using Quartz 1.6.5 on Tomcat 6.0.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the name and group of the job you wish to run "on demand", and you have programmatic access to the scheduler, you could schedule a new SimpleTrigger to run once and immediately.

http://quartz.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/quartz/Scheduler.html

Note that this would not start the cron trigger, I am assuming your goal is to actually run the job your cron trigger points to. If you have code that relies on TriggerListeners listening to your cron trigger, this will not help.